# jquery function not firing on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

looking for some help on a dumb problem.
I have these functions:

```
function update_pred(){
    var sum_pred = 0;
    $('.pred').each(function(){
        var importo_pred = this.value;
        importo_pred = importo_pred.replace(",",".");
        sum_pred += parseFloat(importo_pred);
        $('#pred_tot').html(sum_pred);
    });
}

function update_ipo(){
    var sum_ipo = 0;
    $('.ipo').each(function(){
        var importo_ipo = this.value;
        console.log(importo_ipo);
        importo_ipo = importo_ipo.replace(",",".");
        sum_ipo += parseFloat(importo_ipo);
        console.log(sum_ipo);
        $('#ipo_tot').html(sum_ipo);
    });
}
```

These are supposed to update a table cell based on the values of some other field with a specific class.
If I call each of these functions from a change event in Jquery everything works fine. 
What is not working is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    update_pred();
    update_ipo();
});
```

I am not able to fire the two functions on page load. I load each value from mysql and I want to display the sums on load. 
What do I miss?
Thanks for the help as usual!

Comment: you need to check that your Jquery file loaded properly prior to using $(document).ready.

Comment: thanks a lot but this is already checked. :) I am newbie but not that much!

Comment: If this is the case then table for which you are suppose to fire above function on document ready does not contain data. It may possible that table is also filled with ajax call and when document ready happen ajax call still in process. If this is the case then done at the end of ajax call success method.

Comment: at the moment i am writing the table is filled by php by manually assigning each table cell a value (and this is done before dom is ready).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was related to this piece of code:

```
$('.ipo').each(function(){ 
 $(this).change(function(){ 
  update_ipo(); 
 });
});
```

Turning it to the right form of:

```
$('.ipo').change(function(){ update_ipo(); });
```

did the trick. 
This code was working by itself but was hanging all other javascript from working.